# Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)..js:1 Error: Connection closed

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, backend, next.js13, vercel

when i click the button  the error some that (Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).) and when right click and click open in a new tab it open properly same when i write the route it work properly and also when i open the route once then it start working properly for some time

this error occur in production
in development all is well and works properly

this happened all in nextjs 14 and in vercel

any solution or reason for this to solve the problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx6pV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.